# Locked out of ec2 instance after installing Docker on it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-aws

After I created a clean instance with Ubuntu 20 or Amazon Linux AMI, I can log into the instance using SSH.

Then I do:

`sudo apt update -y && apt upgrade -y on Ubuntu`

or

`sudo yum update -y on Amazon Linux`

Still all goes fine and I can continue to connect to the instance via SSH.

Then I install docker, the pipe becomes broken in the middle of the installation and I cannot connect to the instance any more.
The SSH times out.

This same behavior can be observed also with AMIs with preinstalled Docker on them.
For example I tried to use the redash AMI, I couldn't connect to it after launch.

Comment: You many be running out of ram, cpu or disk on the instance. Have you tried with larger one?

Comment: I'm usin t2.large should be sufficient.